Unable to Create User Account with MT5Manager in Python
I’m trying to create a new user account on the MT5 server using the following Python code, but it’s not working as expected. The connection to the server seems to succeed, but the user creation process either fails or does not return the expected result.
Here is the full code I’m using:
import logging
from MT5Manager import ManagerAPI
import time

# Logging setup
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

MT5_SERVER_ADDRESS = "***"
MT5_LOGIN_ID = 1011
MT5_PASSWORD = "***"

def connect_to_mt5():
    """Connect to the MT5 server with detailed debugging."""
    manager = ManagerAPI()
    try:
        logger.info("Attempting to connect to the MT5 server...")
        response = manager.Connect(MT5_SERVER_ADDRESS, MT5_LOGIN_ID, MT5_PASSWORD, 2, 1000000)
        if response:
            logger.info("Successfully connected to the MT5 server.")
            return manager
        else:
            logger.error("Failed to connect to the MT5 server. Raw response: %s", response)
            return None
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception("Exception occurred during connection to the MT5 server.")
        return None

def add_user(manager, pass_main, pass_investor, group, **kwargs):
    """Create a user account on the MT5 server with minimal data."""
    try:
        logger.info("Preparing user creation request...")
        user_request = {
            "pass_main": pass_main,  # Main password
            "pass_investor": pass_investor,  # Investor password
            "group": group,  # Group name
            "name": kwargs.get("name", "Propiy"),  # Optional name
            "city": kwargs.get("city", "website"),  # Optional city
            "state": kwargs.get("state", "website"),  # Optional state
            "country": kwargs.get("country", "website"),  # Optional country
            "zipcode": kwargs.get("zipcode", "1470"),  # Optional zipcode
        }

        logger.debug("User request data: %s", user_request)
        logger.info("Sending user creation request to the MT5 server...")
        result = manager.UserAdd(user_request)
        logger.debug(f"Raw UserAdd response: {result}")

        if result == 0:
            logger.info("User creation request succeeded.")
            # Retrieve and inspect all users
            logins = manager.UserLogins()
            if logins:
                logger.info("Retrieved logins: %s", logins)
                for login in logins:
                    user_details = manager.UserGet({"Login": login})
                    logger.debug(f"Retrieved user details: {user_details}")
                    # Match user details
                    if user_details and user_details.get("Name") == user_request["name"]:
                        logger.info(f"Successfully located created user with Login ID: {user_details['Login']}")
                        return user_details["Login"]
            logger.error("Failed to locate the created user in the retrieved list.")
        else:
            logger.error(f"User creation failed. Server returned: {result}")
            return None
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception("Exception occurred during user creation.")
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        logger.info("Starting the MT5 user creation script...")
        manager = connect_to_mt5()

        if manager:
            # Add a delay to ensure the server has stabilized between connections
            time.sleep(2)

            # Minimal user info for testing
            pass_main = "Test123!"
            pass_investor = "forex-hedge"
            group = "1"  # Replace with the target group

            # Attempt to create the user
            login_id = add_user(manager, pass_main, pass_investor, group)

            if login_id:
                logger.info(f"User created successfully with Login ID: {login_id}")
            else:
                logger.error("Failed to create the user.")

            # Disconnect from the server
            logger.info("Disconnecting from the MT5 server...")
            manager.Disconnect()
            logger.info("Disconnected successfully.")
        else:
            logger.error("Could not establish a connection to the MT5 server.")
    except Exception as main_exception:
        logger.exception("An unexpected error occurred during execution.")

and I get this result
2024-11-18 15:44:10,428 - INFO - Starting the MT5 user creation script...
2024-11-18 15:44:10,451 - INFO - Attempting to connect to the MT5 server...
2024-11-18 15:44:10,583 - INFO - Successfully connected to the MT5 server.
2024-11-18 15:44:12,584 - INFO - Preparing user creation request...
2024-11-18 15:44:12,584 - DEBUG - User request data: {'pass_main': 'Test123!', 'pass_investor': 'forex-hedge', 'group': '1', 'name': 'Propiy', 'city': 'website', 'state': 'website', 'country': 'website', 'zipcode': '1470'}
2024-11-18 15:44:12,584 - INFO - Sending user creation request to the MT5 server...
2024-11-18 15:44:12,584 - DEBUG - Raw UserAdd response: False
2024-11-18 15:44:12,584 - INFO - User creation request succeeded.
2024-11-18 15:44:12,584 - ERROR - Failed to locate the created user in the retrieved list.
2024-11-18 15:44:12,585 - ERROR - Failed to create the user.
2024-11-18 15:44:12,585 - INFO - Disconnecting from the MT5 server...
2024-11-18 15:44:12,594 - INFO - Disconnected successfully.

The code seems to connect to the MT5 server successfully, but either the UserAdd function fails or the created user cannot be found using UserLogins.
what's is wrong with code?
